# JavaScript concat not working as expected, care to elaborate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, concatenation

So, I have this object containing country names as keys and the values are arrays with some cities. I want to get all the cities in one array, without the countries. Here's how I go about it and can't understand why it isn't working:

```
var cities = {
    "United Kingdom": ['london'],
    "Spain": ['ibiza', 'malaga'],
    "USA": ['hollywood']
}

var allCities = [];
for (c in cities) {
    allCities.concat(cities[c]);
}
console.log(allCities); //gives empty array
```

If I replace `allCities.concat(cities[c])` with `console.log(cities[c])` I get all the arrays like this:

```
['london']
['ibiza', 'malaga']
['hollywood']
```

So that's where my frustration comes from. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per documentation of [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> Returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s)
>   and/or value(s).

Which means it does not modify the object it is applied to.

Change to:

```
allCities = allCities.concat(cities[c]);
```

Comment: @kristiyan.mitev don't forget to mark as answer, if it was helpful for you